# how to cancel svn commit when editing the commit-notes (command line client)

Tags: svn, commit, command-line-interface, svn-client

I'm using the command-line SVN client on Linux. I typed `svn commit` which invoked `vim` to edit the commit notes. When I looked into the list of modified and added files I decided to cancel the commit. But how can I achieve that? Is it already too late?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just [quit the editor without saving](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit), you will be asked to continue or cancel back on the command line.

Like this:

```
Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
```

If you've already saved the message, overwrite your message with the empty message, save again, and quit the editor. `svn` will then abort because of the empty message as well.